# DataTable result to Json, what is wrong with my Json?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, json.net

I'm trying to get the results from SQL stored procedure to DataTable and convert it to Json, so later on I can use it with Highcharts. For some reason the results I'm getting is in wrong format:

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetDailyOutputByHour(int machine, string dateFrom, string dateTo, string line = "All")
    {

        Graph g = repository.Graphs.Where(p => p.GraphID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        string result = repository.GetGraphData(g.StoredProc + " '" + line + "', " + machine + ", '" + dateFrom + "', '" + dateTo + "'");

        return Content(result, "application/json");
    }
```

The repository:

```
public string GetGraphData(string sp)
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFDbContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("exec " + sp, connection))
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Mapped);
            string json =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable, Formatting.Indented);

            return json;
        }
    }
```

The results I'm getting:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Hour\": 7,\r\n    \"Input\": 4614,\r\n    \"Output\": 2952,\r\n    \"InTarget\": 3033,\r\n    \"OutTarget\": 2533\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Hour\": 8,\r\n    \"Input\": 3729,\r\n    \"Output\": 2940,\r\n    \"InTarget\": 3033,\r\n    \"OutTarget\": 2533\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Hour\": 9,\r\n    \"Input\": 4158,\r\n    \"Output\": 3798,\r\n    \"InTarget\": 3033,\r\n    \"OutTarget\": 2533\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Hour\": 10,\r\n    \"Input\": 5310,\r\n    \"Output\": 4023,\r\n    \"InTarget\": 3033,\r\n    \"OutTarget\": 2533\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Hour\": 11,\r\n    \"Input\": 1344,\r\n    \"Output\": 2547,\r\n    \"InTarget\": 3033,\r\n    \"OutTarget\": 2533\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your actually getting the right output boss your looking it the wrong way i think
you should view the output with Text Visualizer in visual studio so i think your output is ok

```
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr;
    DataColumn objstrError;
    DataColumn objBytearr;
    dt = new DataTable();
    objstrError = new DataColumn("strID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    objBytearr = new DataColumn("strName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add(objstrError);
    dt.Columns.Add(objBytearr);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["strID"] = "1";
    dr["strName"] = "Britains got talent";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    string json    =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
     normal intelisense gives:"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"strID\": \"1\",\r\n          \"strName\": \"Britains got talent\"\r\n  }\r\n]"
using TextVisualizer if you see it then looks like this:[
{
"strID": "1",
"strName": "Britains got talent"
 }
]
```

Comment: DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt;
        DataRow dr;
        DataColumn objstrError;
        DataColumn objBytearr;
        dt = new DataTable();
        objstrError = new DataColumn("strID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        objBytearr = new DataColumn("strName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add(objstrError);
        dt.Columns.Add(objBytearr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["strID"] = "1";
        dr["strName"] = "Britains got talent";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Comment: I see that this is correct, but when I pass it to Highchart si not loading any data. When I manually change format (remove alll the \r\n and \) it works.

Comment: use this if it works boss string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

Comment: output using formatting.None :-[{"strID":"1","strName":"Britains got talent"}]

Comment: my output is like this: "[{\"Hour\":7,\"Input\":4614,\"Output\":2952,\"InTarget\":3033,\"OutTarget\":2533},{\"Hour\":8,\"Input\":3729,\"Output\":2940,\"InTarget\":3033,\"OutTarget\":2533},{\"Hour\":9,\"Input\":4158,\"Output\":3798,\"InTarget\":3033,\"OutTarget\":2533},{\"Hour\":10,\"Input\":5310,\"Output\":4023,\"InTarget\":3033,\"OutTarget\":2533},{\"Hour\":11,\"Input\":2055,\"Output\":2991,\"InTarget\":3033,\"OutTarget\":2533},{\"Hour\":12,\"Input\":5520,\"Output\":2118,\"InTarget\":3033,\"OutTarget\":2533}]"

Comment: i don't understand why we are still getting \ in output but something is going wrong but even after removing \ with your json i am getting error but my json just works fine.and its my office time boss so sorry to leave it here

Comment: I need to read more about Highcharts, and what format they are accepting, but cannot find anything for MVC. I get \ because of " as it is use indside the string